# Как найти нормальный вектор?

Tags: математика

Как найти нормальный вектор треугольника, чтоб он был направлен в другую сторону от точки, которая не лежит на плоскости?

*Пример*:
есть треугольник ABC с точками A(0,0,0), B(1,0,0), C(0,1,0) и точка D(0,0,-1)
нормальный вектор будет (0,0,1) (перпендикулярен к плоскости и направлен в противоположную сторону от точки D)

Comment: [Векторное произведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: @extrn треугольник - АВС, а точка D - это любая точка. И моя задача - найти нормальный вектор к треугольнику, который направлен в другую сторону от точки D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нормаль к треугольнику - из векторного произведения любых двух сторон.

Потом скалярно перемножьте нормаль и вектор `AD`. Если произведение отрицательное, нормаль это то, что Вам надо. Если положительное - умножьте нормаль на `-1`.